# Haloalkanes gives acid base reactions or SN2

Tags: acid-base, halides, nucleophilic-substitution

Consider the following reaction:
[image: Reaction]

I am confused whether $SN_2$ reaction will take place or acid - base reaction.
According to me:
This should be an acid - base reaction since the carbonanion(On carbon where chlorine is attached) formed will be stabilized by $p_\pi - d_\pi $ backbonding.

But in many questions, I have seen that they proceed through $SN_2$ mechanism.

Comment: They do both, this will give a mixture of alkene and alcohol

Comment: Which would be the major?

Comment: depends on the conditions

Comment: Like I can decide if a polar protic solvent is given to me?

Comment: Solvent will be one factor, the choice of counterion of the hydroxide will also be important